How remove all copies of duplicates from pyspark dataframe
In this Pyspark Dataframe, there are some records which have duplicates on the ID fields.



ID
start_dt




1
2020-02-09


1
2021-02-15


2
2022-05-04


3
2023-05-15



I want to remove all the records that have duplicates. In this case all rows with ID equals to 1 should be removed.



ID
start_dt




2
2022-05-04


3
2023-05-15



How do I do this in pyspark

You can try to group by id and filter ids with count > 1, then you can join back with this filtered ids to get your desired output
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

data = [(1, "2020-02-09"), (1, "2021-02-15"), (2, "2022-05-04"), (3, "2023-05-15")]
columns = ["ID", "start_dt"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, columns)

df.join(
    df.groupBy("ID").count().filter(col("count") == 1).select("ID"), "ID", "inner"
).show()

